# Is it possible to write a presolved problem into a file?

Tags: optimization, scip, sat

I would like to write a presolved problem into a file. Is there any way to do it?

`write problem` does not do it for me, it gives me the original problem that I read with SCIP.

The context is that I am working on SAT problems. The presolving phase of SCIP reduces the number of constraints and variables of the problem, effectively making the problem a little smaller. I would like to take a look at the presolved problem and compare it with the original problem and make some observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very easy, just use `write transproblem`.

The SCIP interactive shell also tells you all the possible commands that you can use, e.g. if you just type `write` in the SCIP shell, you see all available write commands